# Why does Webview crash at first start?

Tags: android, crash, webview

In my Android app, when I create a new emulator and try to write in webview for the first time, it's not active. I can't write in textfield and then the app crashes. If I reload the app all works OK.

Code:

```
String url = "http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=2731649&scope=wall,notify,docs&" +
            "redirect_uri=http://api.vkontakte.ru/blank.html&display=wap&response_type=token";
    WebViewClass wvClforVK = new WebViewClass();
```

In oncreate:

```
webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.vkWebView);
         webview.setWebViewClient(wvClforVK);
```

On buttonclick:

```
webview.loadUrl(url);
in wvClforVK
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url); 
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Are you calling `setContentView(...)` BEFORE you call `findViewById(R.id.vkWebView)`?

Comment: is it this.setContentView(R.layout.main); ? yes

Comment: Yes, that should be it (as long as your layout file is called `main.xml`). You don't put the .xml part on it when using `R.layout.` as you show in your comment. You must set the content view BEFORE attempting to use any components such as your `R.id.vkWebView`. If you use `findViewById` before setting content view, it will return `null`

Comment: @MisterSquonk write it as an answer so you get the points not as comment

Comment: it was need to put webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN); after webview.loadUrl(url);

Comment: @AntonSobolev you should now accept his answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the content view BEFORE attempting to use any components such as your R.id.vkWebView. If you use `findViewById(...)` before setting content view, it will return null.

To set the content view call...

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

...assuming your layout file is called `main.xml` but you don't put the .xml part on it when using R.layout. Usually you will set the content view as early in an activity's `onCreate(...)` method as possible. This is often done immediately after the call to `super.onCreate(...);`

Comment: This answer fixed the problem I was having. I had the setContentView call after the loadUrl attempt, which caused the crashing. Moving setContentView before any of my WebView code fixed the crash I was encountering.

Answer (score 1):

For android 4.2.2, 
Add loadUrl("about:blank") before you start loading your desired URL.

So,the final code is

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_web_view);
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
webview.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Before adding `loadUrl("about:blank")`, when i run my app on android 4.2.2 crash everytime my webview try to load Url.

Comment: Thanks for this it solves a crash for me too. But WHY does this work!? :/